# Report Builder 2.0 Data Source Credentials Prompt

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have two saved shared data sources that are virtually identical but have different names and have been deployed to the report server at different times. They both live in the DataSources folder on the report server and I have rights assigned at the folder level.

One is named PDB and one PDB2. They both use the same SQL Server account and password and point to same database. Both store the credentials securely within the data source.

The difference is that the newer one, PDB2, prompts me for credentials when I attempt to use the data source from Report Builder 2. PDB, however, does not prompt me to reenter my credentials. Of course, since the credentials ARE stored in the data source, I should NEVER be prompted for my creentials.

I can't figure out why this is happening. Anybody have any idea?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, in the Report Data section, the data source properties has General and Credentials sections.  In credentials there is an option to "Prompt for credential" and a place you can enter the prompt text.  Make sure this option is not selected, then save and deploy it.

In the Report Manager also check the shared sata source properties.  The credential setting for both should be the same, and the groups or users in security should be the same.  Another place to check in the Report Manager is the properties of the actual report.  Select the Data Sources section and see if the data source and credential settings match.  The security properties should also match.

Take a look and verify these are all set correctly to match the other data source or report.

Comment: Thanks. But I have checked all of those. I am a fairly advanced developer/user. All the settings are correct and identical between the two data sources. It's almost as if the credentials are not being stored correctly with the data source.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues, just use the SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio. It is the most reliable method until Report Builder 2.0 gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried diffing the 2 .rds files?
What about deleting the data sources from the server and re-deploying (take a back-up before doing so if you can?).

I've been encountering similar kinds of issues with Reporting Services 2008 over the last few days, and both of these two actions have thrown new light onto the problem for me.